# Please confirm/comment on Branch Coverage issue I'm seeing with EclEmma Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

After running this unit testing using EclEmma Eclipse code coverage plugin, it returns 100% Branch coverage, i.e. 4 out of 4 branches covered, I expect only 2 out of 4 branches covered here i.e. 50% coverage.
If I turn out to be correct can anyone suggest a better branch coverage tool please. Thanks in advance.

```
@Test
public void testTT(){;
    assertTrue(bar(true, true)==3);
}

@Test
public void testFF(){;
    assertTrue(bar(false, false)==8);
}


int bar(boolean cond1, boolean cond2) {
      int answer = 1;
      if (cond1) {
          answer = answer * a();
      } else {
          answer = answer * b();
      }

      if (cond2) {
          answer = answer * c();
      } else {
          answer = answer * d();
      }
    return answer;
    }

private int a(){
    return 1;
}

private int b(){
    return 2;
}

private int c(){
    return 3;
}

private int d(){
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, after looking a round I found JMockit: http://jmockit.org which offers path coverage, seems to work for the simple cases I have tested it with. I have also seen some commercial tools which seem to offer path coverage, https://www.parasoft.com and http://www.coverity.com/products/coverity-save/

Answer (score 1):

The tool is being correct. You have 4 branches in the code, and all 4 of them are exercised.

I believe what you are looking for is the combinatorial complexity on how many unique paths through the entire code there is, and have a measure for that. In your example the number of branches happens to equal the number of paths through the whole method.

I can demonstrate the difference with a slightly longer example:

```java
@Test
public void testTTT(){;
    assertTrue(bar(true, true, true)==3);
}

@Test
public void testFFF(){;
    assertTrue(bar(false, false, false)==8);
}


int bar(boolean cond1, boolean cond2, boolean cond3) {
      int answer = 1;
      if (cond1) {
          answer = answer * a();
      } else {
          answer = answer * b();
      }

      if (cond2) {
          answer = answer * c();
      } else {
          answer = answer * d();
      }

      if (cond3) {
          answer = answer * c();
      } else {
          answer = answer * d();
      }
      return answer;
}
```

In the above example, there are 6 branch conditions, all covered with just two tests. But there are 8 code paths through the whole function.

There is no tool that maps out every possible code path (pretty sure doing so would be solving an [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem.) Of course, testing all possible inputs of a (non-trivial) program is unrealistic. Using code coverage is one tool to help ensure your program is well tested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between branch coverage and path coverage.  Your function `bar` has four branches, namely one THEN and one ELSE branch for each of the two IF statements.  And, your two test cases actually cover all these four branches.  The first test covers the two THEN branches, the second test covers the two ELSE branches.  That is 100% of all branches.

Regarding path coverage, your code example has four paths: a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, and of these only a-c and b-d are covered.  When you expected a coverage of only 50%, you probably had the paths in mind.

Normally, path coverage is not handled by coverage tools: The number of paths quickly explodes, and, in case of loops would have to be considered as infinite by the tools (except in special cases and only if the coverage tool would care for the necessary static analysis to discover these cases).

If your concern is the quality of your test suite, I suggest not to limit your focus on code coverage analyses, but to also take other possibilities for designing / evaluating the test suite into account, like for example requirement coverage, equivalence partitioning with boundary case analysis, mutation testing, ...